# The application is not approved to use the following parameters with this type of payment

Tags: cordova, paypal, phonegap-plugins, paypal-sandbox

I've download paypal mpl and using phonegap default example to test sandbox.

I just change these line from example

```
obj.paymentAmount = document.getElementById('pmt_subtotal').value;
obj.paymentCurrency = document.getElementById('pmt_currency').value;
obj.recipient = document.getElementById('pmt_recipient').value;
obj.merchantName = document.getElementById('pmt_merchant').value;
obj.itemDesc = document.getElementById('pmt_description').value;
obj.memo = document.getElementById('pmt_memo').value;
obj.tax = document.getElementById('pmt_tax').value;
obj.shipping = document.getElementById('pmt_shipping').value;
```

with this static value

```
var obj = {
        server : 'ENV_SANDBOX',
        appId : 'APP-80W284485P519543T'
    };
obj.paymentAmount = 10.0;
obj.paymentCurrency = 'USD';
obj.recipient = 'moin_k_1347963077_biz@yahoo.com';
obj.merchantName = 'Test Test';
obj.itemDesc = 'something';
obj.memo = 'something';
obj.tax = 0;
obj.shipping = 0;
```

When i click paypal pay button it throws an error

`"The application is not approved to use the following parameters with this type of payment".`

Here is the complete eclipse project http://marinefreshbd.com/paypal/Paypal.zip

Comment: Can you submit a sample of the actual request that's getting generated and the endpoint that you're using?  I'm guessing you may be posting to an incorrect endpoint or the request isn't really including the app ID like it should.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, for me, was updated mpl.java file like said in this link

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/eclipse-plugin-for-phonegap/UnHBZ_u_TDM/Z8W432aGG4UJ

Hope it helps you. Good luck.

Aurelio

Comment: Please consider not leaving link only answers, if that link ever becomes invalid this answer also becomes useless.